# cron expression for every hour starting from specific time

Tags: node.js, cron, cronexpression

I am able to schedule using this cron expression using nodejs cron-job every one hour (starting from "now").

But I need to set q cron every one hour starting from a specific time. E.g let's say starts from 3:30 AM. can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean starting at 3:30am and then running every hour until midnight? What about when it rolls to the next day? Should it then stop between midnight and 3:30am?

Comment: Its starts from 3.30 and its executes every hour every day

Answer (score 7):

The `/` character allows you to give two expressions to a cron part. The first is a "starting at" argument and the second is "every X units". So, a cron that will run every hour, starting at 03:30 (I.e., at 03:30, 04:30, 05:30, etc.) would look like this:

```
0 30 3/1 * * * *
```

Comment: I scheduled  '0 19 13/1 * * *' cron expression . its triggered only at 13.19  after an hour 14:19 time its not triggered. Anything i missed?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
30 3/1 * * * * *
```

Comment: Can You please explain what your cron statement means ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Mureinik's answer, just "starting at" on the first argument is non-standard and it may not work with every cron. The standard format should be

startingAt-endingAt/forEvery

example: 30 3-23/1 * * *